# Find an example $E=\cup{_{\alpha∈A}}E_\alpha$ such that $m_\star(E)\leq\sum{_{\alpha∈A}}m_\star(E_\alpha)$ does not hold.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The exterior measure satisfy the countable sub-additivity, i.e., if  $E=\cup{_{i=1}^{+\infty}}E_i$,then $m_\star(E)\leq\sum{_{i=1}^{+\infty}}m_\star(E_i)$.If $E=\cup{_{\alpha∈A}}E_\alpha$,where A is any indexed family,the sub-additivity $m_\star(E)\leq\sum{_{\alpha∈A}}m_\star(E_\alpha)$ may not hold.I want to find an example.

My example:Considering the set of irrational number on [0,1],denoted by $E$,$E=\cup{_{\alpha∈A}}E_\alpha$ where each $E_\alpha$ is an irrational number in [0,1].And $m_\star(E)$=1, $\sum{_{\alpha∈A}}m_\star(E_\alpha)=0$.

Is my example correct?

Comment: I want to find an example whose index set is uncountable and the "sub-additivity" does not hold.

Comment: I am extremely sorry... :) your example does makes sense as of i am concerned...  your example is correct...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example (using the Lebesgue measure, I presume) is correct. It could be stated simpler as: $[0,1]$ is the union of singletons $\{x\}$, each of which has zero Lebesgue measure.